# Send SMS By android app using web server (clickatell)

Tags: sms

I create an android app and i want to send SMS through API provider like clickatell ( i will bay for the SMS that i will send )

i use the same code that in the website

but when i run it , unfortunately it stooped

```js
public void onClick(View v) {

  try {
    Properties theprops = new Properties();
    theprops.setProperty("smsj.clickatell.username", "username");
    theprops.setProperty("smsj.clickatell.password", "password");
    theprops.setProperty("smsj.clickatell.apiid", "id");
    // Load the clickatell transport
    SmsTransport transport = SmsTransportManager.getTransport("org.marre.sms.transport.clickatell.ClickatellTransport", theprops);
    // Connect to clickatell
    transport.connect();
    // Create the sms message
    SmsTextMessage textMessage = new SmsTextMessage("A sample SMS.");
    // Send the sms to "461234" from "461235"
    transport.send(textMessage, new SmsAddress("my saudi phone number"),
      new SmsAddress("emulator-5554\temulator-5554\tOnline\tLaunchCompatibility{compatible=YES, reason=null}"));
    // Disconnect from clickatell
    transport.disconnect();
  } catch (IOException io) {
    io.printStackTrace();
    System.out.println("i");
  } catch (SmsException s) {
    s.printStackTrace();
    System.out.println("s");
  }
}
```

i don't know what is my problem ? may be in manifest permission !

please help me

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: when i click the button to run  the function my program top and the emulater show this message (unfortunately your program stooped)